# Show that $\|A(I - vv^T/v^Tv)\|_F^2 = \|A\|_F^2 - \|Av\|^2_2/(v^tv)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

> Show that $\|A(I - vv^T/v^Tv)\|_F^2 = \|A\|_F^2 - \|Av\|^2_2/(v^tv), A \in R^{n \times n}, v \in R^n$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\|A(I - vv^T/v^Tv)\|_F^2 
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}(A - Avv^T/c)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}(A^2 + (Avv^T)^2/c^2 - 2A^2vv^T/c) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}A^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}(vv^TA^TAvv^T/c^2 - 2A^TAvv^T/c)\\
&= \|A\|_F^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}(vv^TA^TAvv^T/c^2 - 2A^TAvv^T/c)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Where are the subscripts?

Comment: @user10354138 I guess you were asking what the subscripts mean. I edited the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simplify this by assuming WLOG that $\mathbf v$ has length one.

**simple case:**
suppose $\mathbf v := \mathbf e_1$, the first standard basis vector. Then by direct computation
$\|A(I - \mathbf{e_1e_1}^T)\|_F^2  =\sum_{j=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,j}^2$  and
$\|A\|_F^2 - \|A\mathbf e_1\|_2^2 =\big(\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,j}^2\big)  -\big(\sum_{j=1}^1\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,j}^2\big)= \sum_{j=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,j}^2$
hence $\|A(I - \mathbf{e_1e_1}^T)\|_F^2=\|A\|_F^2 - \|A\mathbf e_1\|_2^2$

**general case:**
Real symmetric matrices may be orthogonally diagonalizaed, so $\big(I-\mathbf {vv}^T\big) =Q\big(I -\mathbf e_1\mathbf e_1^T\big)Q^T$, where $Q$ is real orthogonal.  Define $B:=Q^TAQ$

$\|A(I - \mathbf{vv}^T)\|_F^2$
$=\|AQ(I - \mathbf e_1\mathbf e_1^T)Q^T\|_F^2$
$=\|Q^TAQ(I - \mathbf e_1\mathbf e_1^T)\|_F^2$
$=\|B(I - \mathbf e_1\mathbf e_1^T)\|_F^2$
$=\|B\|_F^2 - \|B\mathbf e_1\|_2^2$
$=\|Q^TAQ\|_F^2 - \|Q^TAQ\mathbf e_1\|_2^2$
$=\|A\|_F^2 - \|A(Q\mathbf e_1)\|_2^2$
$=\|A\|_F^2 - \|A\mathbf v\|_2^2$